# What logical fallacy considers a personal experience to be common place

Tags: logic

While my wife and I were discussing the news a few days ago I stated  that an argument expressed (in a news article, not by my wife) was a fallacy -- but I've been unable to put a name to it.

Basically, it is when a person experiences some experience (personally or thru acquaintance), and thus considers it a common experience because they have experienced it.

Comment: Probably looking for: "black swan fallacy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a ["Hasty Generalization"](https://www.thoughtco.com/hasty-generalization-fallacy-1690919) which is drawing too broad a conclusion from too limited a dataset.  It often results from taking personal anecdotal evidence as decisive.

It's a very common fallacy, because we all tend to do it unless specifically on guard against it (or is that statement itself a hasty generalization?).